# object destructuring when key has dot character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object-destructuring

```js
var x = { "a": 1, "b": 3 }

const { a } = x

console.log(a)
```

For the above code output is `1` as expected.

```js
var x = { "a.0.0": 1, "b": 3 }

const { a.0.0 } = x

console.log(a)
```

but when the key has dot character in it, the output is `undefined`. How can I destructure when the key has dot characters in it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take  the key as string and another variable name for getting a valid variable. ([Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names))

```js
var x  = { "a.0.0": 1, b: 3 };

const { 'a.0.0': a } = x;

console.log(a);
```

Comment: You have quite a lot of rep already, it might be helpful to switch your default to finding duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here's the code to solve this :)

```js
var x  = {"a.0.0":1,"b":3}

const {"a.0.0": a1} = x;
//or
const a2 = x["a.0.0"]

console.log(a1, a2)
```